# Is it possible to restore MS SQL backup databases that are in excess of 10 GB for free?

Tags: sql, database, file, backup, restore

I am currently using Microsoft SQL Server Studio Management Express to restore MS SQL backup file databases. Although the majority of my files are less than 10 GB, there are some that are greater.

Is there a possible solution to restore the files greater than 10 GB for free?

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

No there is no way you can do this if the data file is greater than 10GB.
The size limit is for the data file(log file excluded).
The database size limit was raised to 10GB in 2008 R2 and 2012.Remains the same in 2014 too. This 10GB limit only applies to relational data, and Filestream data does not count towards this limit (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895334.aspx)

But if you were trying to take a backup and restore a database with the datafile larger than 10GB it will not work.

That would probably be one the best hacks if it could be done :)

Comment: Ah, I see. I suppose what I was trying to ask was is there another solution that doesn't use Microsoft SQL Server Studio Management? Perhaps a free third-party tool? Obviously, I realize that this would be a long shot..

Comment: Apparently there isn't any.